# Adding dropdown menu changed order of links on navbar and other formatting

Tags: ruby

I need some help figuring out why adding a dropdown menu changed the order of buttons on my navbar.

I added a dropdown menu that opens when a user hovers on the button by following the "CSS Dropdown" guide on w3schools.

For whatever reason, implementing this code rearranged my buttons on the Navbar. It used to consist of About Me-> Workshop offerings-> Contact Us. Now, it is About Me-> Contact Us-> Workshop Offerings.

I went back to check the CSS for anything overriding code but was unable to find anything.

I also noticed that the class of the button was changed from a

to  for a hyperlink (the button text color changed and had an underline like a normal hyperlink. I since removed that formatting but it got me thinking what could have changed all this.)

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot adding a responsive button that would change the order of navbar items as well as overriding the

formatting?

I have tried adding color:white overrides to replace the text color and text-color when hovering. I ended up creating a .navbar a {} class that fixed the problem...however I was unable to fix the navbar order. I would like to fix the overriding on the colors so I don't have unnecessary code too.

My application.html.erb code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Saasapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/", type: 'text/javascript' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

     <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
       <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
       C. R. Communication Strategies
      <% end %>

    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"><li><%= link_to "Offerings", offerings_path %></li></button>

        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li><%= link_to "Public Speaking", pages_public_speaking_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Nonverbal Communication", nonverbal_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Group Dynamics", group_dynamics_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Intercultural Communication", intercultural_communication_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Editing", editing_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Interviewing", interviewing_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Business Etiquette", business_etiquette_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Business Writing", business_writing_path %></li>
        </div>
      </div>

      <li><%= link_to "Contact Form", new_contact_path %></li>

    </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

  <div class="container flash-container">
    <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{type}" %>
    <% end %>  
  </div>    


    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My application.css.scss code:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
* files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
* It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome-sprockets';
@import 'font-awesome';

//Typography Styles
h1, h2, h3  {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif'
}

// Background Gradient
.navbar, .home-callout {
    //Gradient provided by @i_ghosh at uiGradients.com
    background: #000046;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #1CB5E0, #000046);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1CB5E0, #000046); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

//Nav Styles
}

.navbar {
  border: none;
}

// Color of hyperlinks on navbar (Offerings)
.navbar a {
  color:white;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.75;
    text-decoration:none;
  }
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border: 2px solid white;
    &:hover, &:focus {
  background-color: #1CB5E0;
  }
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

// Home Page Styles
.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:white;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}


// Margin between navbar and rest of the page
 .home-signup-links {
   margin-top: 05px;
 }


// Styles for upper text and image on home page
.header-box {
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-box h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.header-box img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  margin-left: 750px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 500px;
}

//Large header across center of the page
.text-upper {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.3 !important;
  margin: 60px 0 20px 0;
}

//Style for second header 
.paragraph-upper {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.3 !important;
  margin: 0px 0 60px 0;
}

.button {
  width: 30%;
  padding-left: 190px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


// This is just buffer to push the page down
.button p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.lower-page {
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 100%;

}

.lower-page-content {
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif !important;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.lower-heading {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.lower-paragraph {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.home-callout{
  color:white;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.flash-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.alert-notice, .alert-alert {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin-top: -14px;
}


.class {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

//About Me

.about-image {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

// Offerings Page

.row-fluid {
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1.3 !important;
  margin: 0 0 .75em 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px; 
}

//Horizantal Line Style
hr {

  width: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
}

.top-paragraph {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.offerings-row {
 width: 100%; 
}

.course-image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.blue-header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif !important;
  color: #075dab;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.offerings-info {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

// Public Speaking

.workshop-image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.course-summary {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Please let me know if this code is sufficient, or if I should add other file code to allow anyone helping to replicate the scenario.

Comment: Please add your code in a way that we can reproduce your problem. With the code you posted, we cannot.

Comment: @B-M I updated the post to include my full code for those files. Is that enough to replicate?

Comment: @b-m can you look at my code now if you had a few minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really reproduce your example, however, this code worked for me:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_path %>"><i class="fa fa-group"></i>C. R. Communication Strategies</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <button class="dropbtn"><li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li></button>
      <div class="dropdown mx-auto">
        <button class="dropbtn"><li><%= link_to "Offerings", offerings_path %></li></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li><%= link_to "Public Speaking", pages_public_speaking_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Nonverbal Communication", nonverbal_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Group Dynamics", group_dynamics_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Intercultural Communication", intercultural_communication_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Editing", editing_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Interviewing", interviewing_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Business Etiquette", business_etiquette_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Business Writing", business_writing_path %></li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="dropbtn"><li><%= link_to "Contact Form", new_contact_path %></li></button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you so much. Adding the button class fixed it. Also helped with keeping the format for all 3 buttons the same. You rock!

Comment: No problem, @Mikerich94. If this helped, mark the answer as correct : )